# async function in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code snippet:

```
import asyncio

def main():
    asyncio.run(work())
    print("BEFORE")

async def work():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("AFTER")

main()
```

I would like "BEFORE" to be printed first, followed by "AFTER" however this prints "AFTER" first instead - have I misunderstood how async functions work? I thought that running `asyncio.run(...)` would allow my code to skip to `print("BEFORE")` while still running `work()` in the background.

Ideal output is:

```
BEFORE
AFTER
```

Right now it's

```
AFTER
BEFORE
```

Comment: `asyncio.run(work)`

Comment: The `asyncio.run` is the entry point to your coroutines. It runs to completion, which means it blocks until the top-level coroutine returns.

Comment: In other words, it won't work as you expect.

Comment: Is there something I can use that's the equivalent of asyncio.run but non-blocking? I need main() to return before work() without introducing any extra functions

Comment: No, something needs to run your coroutine. If your main function exits, that should be the end of your program. whatever comes after `asyncio.run()` could just be put in the `work` function, or another one, a top-level `amain` for example.

Answer (score 0):

`run` seems to be blocking, so you might want to just use `gather` here:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(work(), setup())
    print('After gather')

async def work():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("AFTER")

async def setup():
    print("BEFORE")

asyncio.run(main())
```

This correctly prints

```
BEFORE
AFTER
After gather
```

The entire gather statement itself is blocking as well, but all of the functions specified in the gather statement can run asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for this - the actual code behind this is little more complex in that I need main() to finish execution before either work() or setup(). The reason behind this is I'm coding a bot in Slack where I need to respond with a return value of 200 within main() but also process work in a background function after that 200 has been returned from main() specifically - not another function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines):

> The asyncio.run() function to run the top-level entry point “main()” function (see the above example.)

The `asyncio.run` should be the entry point, not used for starting a background job. So it does not skip to `print("BEFORE")`.